# how to run react project created with "create-react-app" in codepen?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I've created very basic react project with `create-react-app` command and wish to run in `codepen`

I did below settings under JS

[image]

To run project locally I use command `npm run`, how to achieve that in codepen ?

Comment: You can use codesandbox.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` compiles all the code into one or many javascript files. You cannot do that in codepen.
You can use codepen with pre-compiled react files but you won't get what you would expect from `create-react-app`.

See this Hello World example:
https://reactjs.org/redirect-to-codepen/hello-world

There are other sites like [glitch.me](https://glitch.me), [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io) where you can clone the repo of `create-react-app` and use the node environment.